# Creating nearest neighbors Laplacian matrix

Tags: matrices, matlab, graph-laplacian, circulant-matrices

I want to create a general formula for an $N \times N$ nearest neighbors Laplacian matrix such that I can write an mfile in MATLAB to compute the matrix for given $N$.

The nearest neighbors Laplacian matrix is of the below form

\begin{equation}
L=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
-2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1\\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & -2\\
\end{array}
\right].
\end{equation}

where the main diagonal elements are all $-2$ and we have two elements of $1$ before and after each element in the main diagonal.

Would appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2):

I might be misreading what you have written as the $L$ matrix, but I believe you can use:

L = gallery('tridiag',ones(1,N-1),-2*ones(1,N),ones(1,N-1));

This will return the tridiaganol matrix in sparse form. You can wrap it in full() to convert it to a standard matrix. Then you can manually change the top and bottom corners to 1.

Let me know if this works or if I've misunderstood the form of L.

Comment: You can also set the corners within the sparse representation, if desired.

Comment: @Ian, absolutely, and that is necessary if the matrix is too large to create in full form.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this for full matrices is:

```
>> N=5;
>> L=diag(-2*ones(1,N),0)+diag(ones(1,N-1),1)+diag(ones(1,N-1),-1)
L =

  -2   1   0   0   0
   1  -2   1   0   0
   0   1  -2   1   0
   0   0   1  -2   1
   0   0   0   1  -2

>> L(1,N)=1
L =

  -2   1   0   0   1
   1  -2   1   0   0
   0   1  -2   1   0
   0   0   1  -2   1
   0   0   0   1  -2

>> L(N,1)=1
L =

  -2   1   0   0   1
   1  -2   1   0   0
   0   1  -2   1   0
   0   0   1  -2   1
   1   0   0   1  -2

>>
```

Comment: If N is large, this implementation takes appreciably longer. For example, N=10000, using the full(gallery) function takes on the order of 1e-2 seconds (on my machine), and this takes on the order of 1 second. Not sure if that matters or not. And for larger matrices, the gallery will let you generate it in sparse form as written, which may be convenient.

Answer (score 0):

That symmetric matrix is almost a tridiagonal [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) matrix. Hence,

```
r = [-2, 1, zeros(1,n-2)];
L = toeplitz(r);
```

Update now the northeast and southwest corners:

```
L(1,n) = 1;
L(n,1) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For small matrices (e.g. $n=10$), try

```
L = eye(10)
L = circshift(L,[1 0]) + circshift(L,[0 1]) - 2*L
```

For larger dimensions (e.g. $n=1000$), you'll probably want a sparse matrix

```
L = speye(1000)
L = circshift(L,[1 0]) + circshift(L,[0 1]) - 2*L
```